# How to replace every function call with the wrapper call in the original class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have two classes, one of which is a wrapper of the other. A function in the original class uses a method called `forward`, but I want it to use the `forward` method of the wrapper class after it has been wrapped, not the original. For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.a + x

    def main(self, x):
        return self.forward(x) + 100


class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, A):
        self.module = A

    def forward(self, x):
        # Long convoluted code.
        # ..
        # ..

        return self.module.forward(x)


classA = A()
wrapperA = Wrapper(classA)

# Goal: Make classA.main(..) use the forward function from Wrapper instead.
```

Because the wrapper class has the long and convoluted code that needs to be run, I want all calls of `forward` from `main` to be such that it calls the `forward` from the wrapper class, not from the original.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Reasons why I did not use inheritance:

1. Instantiating class A is memory intensive. If I receive class A object as input, I want to modify its core behavior. without instantiating another object.
2. `classA` can be of different object types in runtime.

--

An alternative way I thought of is to redefine `main` in `Wrapper`. However, the problem is doing this automatically for every method defined in A without hard coding.

Comment: Why does it have to be a wrapper, and not an inherited class? That would solve that problem automatically.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I was also thinking about this but it seems that the inherited class would need to dynamically infer the the class to inherit at runtime, since in reality classA can be of different classes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you influence how `A` is instantiated, or do you simply get an instance from somewhere?

Comment: Yes I can get an instance from somewhere for A

Comment: You could override `__getattr__()` in a `Wrapper` class and forward calls and attribute access to an instance of class `A` that is passed to it as an argument when it's created. Likewise for `__setattr__`. The same instance of `A` could be wrapped by more than one `Wrapper` (or kind of `Wrapper`), so you may not need to create many of them.

Answer (score 4):

In Python "everything is an object". Including classes, functions, and methods
on objects.

As such we can take any class, loop over all functions in that class and modify
them as needed.

Depending on the real code, the problem in the question might be better tackled
using decorators or meta-classes, depending on the dependencies of the wrapper
(what values does it need access to). I will not go into meta-classes as most needs for meta-classes can also be implemented using class-decorators, which are less error-prone.

As you mention in one of your comments that you may have several different classes that need to be wrapped the class-decorator solution might be a good candidate. This way you won't lose the inheritance tree of the wrapped class.

Here is an example not using either, but doing exactly as asked ;)

## Using `__new__`

```
from functools import update_wrapper


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        docstring (to demonstrate `update_wrapper`
        """
        print("original forward")
        return self.a + x

    def main(self, x):
        return self.forward(x) + 100


class Wrapper:

    # Using __new__ instead of __init__ gives us complete control *how* the
    # "Wrapper" instance is created. We use it to "pull in" methods from *A*
    # and dynamically attach them to the `Wrapper` instance using `setattr`.
    #
    # Using __new__ is error-prone however, and using either meta-classes or
    # even easier, decorators would be more maintainable.
    def __new__(cls, A):

        # instance will be our instance of thie `Wrapper` class. We start off
        # with no defined functions, we will add those soon...
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance.module = A

        # We now walk over every "name" in the wrapped class
        for funcname in dir(A):
            # We skip anything starting with two underscores. They are most
            # likely magic methods that we don't want to wrap with the
            # additional code. The conditions what exactly we want to wrap, can
            # be adapted as needed.
            if funcname.startswith("__"):
                continue

            # We now need to get a reference to that attribute and check if
            # it's callable. If not it is a member variable or something else
            # and we can/should skip it.
            func = getattr(A, funcname)
            if not callable(func):
                continue

            # Now we "wrap" the function with our additional code. This is done
            # in a separate function to keep __new__ somewhat clean
            wrapped = Wrapper._wrap(func)

            # After wrapping the function we can attach that new function ont
            # our `Wrapper` instance
            setattr(instance, funcname, wrapped)

        return instance

    @staticmethod
    def _wrap(func):
        """
        Wraps *func* with additional code.
        """
        # we define a wrapper function. This will execute all additional code
        # before and after the "real" function.
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print("before-call:", func, args, kwargs)
            output = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("after-call:", func, args, kwargs, output)
            return output
        # Use "update_wrapper" to keep docstrings and other function metadata
        # intact
        update_wrapper(wrapped, func)

        # We can now return the wrapped function
        return wrapped



class Demo2:

    def foo(self):
        print("yoinks")


classA = A()
otherInstance = Demo2()
wrapperA = Wrapper(classA)
wrapperB = Wrapper(otherInstance)
print(wrapperA.forward(10))
print(wrapperB.foo())
print("docstring is maintained: %r" % wrapperA.forward.__doc__)
```

## Using a class decorator

With a class decorator, there is no need to override `__new__` which can lead to hard to debug issues if not 100% properly implemented.

However, it has a key difference: It modifies the existing class "in-place", so the original class is lost in a way. Although you *could* keep a reference to it in the unlikely case that you need to.

Modifying this in-place does however also mean that you don't need to replace all your usages in your application with the new "wrapper" class, making it a lot easier to implement in an existing code-base and eliminating the risk that you forget to apply the wrapper on new instances.

```
from functools import update_wrapper


def _wrap(func):
    """
    Wraps *func* with additional code.
    """
    # we define a wrapper function. This will execute all additional code
    # before and after the "real" function.
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print("before-call:", func, args, kwargs)
        output = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("after-call:", func, args, kwargs, output)
        return output
    # Use "update_wrapper" to keep docstrings and other function metadata
    # intact
    update_wrapper(wrapped, func)

    # We can now return the wrapped function
    return wrapped


def wrapper(cls):
    for funcname in dir(cls):
        # We skip anything starting with two underscores. They are most
        # likely magic methods that we don't want to wrap with the
        # additional code. The conditions what exactly we want to wrap, can
        # be adapted as needed.
        if funcname.startswith("__"):
            continue

        # We now need to get a reference to that attribute and check if
        # it's callable. If not it is a member variable or something else
        # and we can/should skip it.
        func = getattr(cls, funcname)
        if not callable(func):
            continue

        # Now we "wrap" the function with our additional code. This is done
        # in a separate function to keep __new__ somewhat clean
        wrapped = _wrap(func)

        # After wrapping the function we can attach that new function ont
        # our `Wrapper` instance
        setattr(cls, funcname, wrapped)
    return cls


@wrapper
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        docstring (to demonstrate `update_wrapper`
        """
        print("original forward")
        return self.a + x

    def main(self, x):
        return self.forward(x) + 100


@wrapper
class Demo2:

    def foo(self):
        print("yoinks")


classA = A()
otherInstance = Demo2()
print(classA.forward(10))
print(otherInstance.foo())
print("docstring is maintained: %r" % classA.forward.__doc__)
```

## Using function decorators

Another alternative, which diverges largely from the original question but may still prove insightful is using individual functions wrappers.

The code still used the same wrapper function, but here functions/methods are annotated individually.

This might give more flexibility by offering the possibility to leave some methods "unwrapped", but could easily lead to the wrapping code being executed more often than anticipated as demonstrated in the `main()` method.

```
from functools import update_wrapper


def wrap(func):
    """
    Wraps *func* with additional code.
    """
    # we define a wrapper function. This will execute all additional code
    # before and after the "real" function.
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print("before-call:", func, args, kwargs)
        output = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("after-call:", func, args, kwargs, output)
        return output
    # Use "update_wrapper" to keep docstrings and other function metadata
    # intact
    update_wrapper(wrapped, func)

    # We can now return the wrapped function
    return wrapped


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    @wrap
    def forward(self, x):
        """
        docstring (to demonstrate `update_wrapper`
        """
        print("original forward")
        return self.a + x

    @wrap  # careful: will be wrapped twice!
    def main(self, x):
        return self.forward(x) + 100

    def foo(self):
        print("yoinks")


classA = A()
print(">>> forward")
print(classA.forward(10))
print("<<< forward")
print(">>> main")
print(classA.main(100))
print("<<< main")
print(">>> foo")
print(classA.foo())
print("<<< foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could inherit `Wrapper` from `A`, and use `super` to access the parent class.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, child):
        self.a = 1
        self.child = child

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.a + x

    def main(self, x):
        return self.child.forward(x) + 100

class Wrapper(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Wrapper, self).__init__(self, self)

    def forward(x):
        return "whatever"

wrapperA = Wrapper()
```

But if you wish to use class `A`, just inherit `A` from `Wrapper`. Otherwise, I can't figure out whats wrong. Please don't use functions indiscriminate. Make a class you wish to use, and another one act as a parent and don't mix roles.

```
#...
class A(Wrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__(self)
#...
```

Comment: Wouldn't this skip the long and convoluted code from Wrapper class (see above)?

Comment: @oldselflearner1959. That code goes in the child class, as it did in the wrapper before. Now you can call `main` on the wrapper and get the convoluted code to run

Comment: You can pass a reference of wrapper to its parent, and when you call A.main, just run through the reference. I'll edit my post.